# Unable to mount docker folder into host using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Here I created docker container which use the `mariadb` image and created three volumes as below.

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.0'

services:
  mariadb:
  image: mariadb:latest
  restart: always
  container_name: mariadb
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=testdb
  ports:
   - 3307:3306
  volumes:
   - ./database:/var/lib/mysql
   - ./_conf/mariadb.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf:ro
   - ./logs:/var/log/mysql
```

First two volume works successfully but I can't able to find mariadb-logs files into `logs` folder. I seems `logs` folder showing blank on host as well as on container(/var/log/mysql). I think host folder override into docker file system.

If I remove this volume(`./logs:/var/log/mysql`) from docker-compose then logs files are showing on container.

My plan is to mount `/var/log/mysql/` folder to local machine.

Thanks !

Comment: Try `chmod 777 /var/log/mysql` on your host, I bet your daemon running as `mysql` user has no rights to write in this directory on your host. After that you'll have to find the mysql user id inside the container to make a `chown` to avoid lettign everyone read an write your  db logs.

Comment: Perhaps selinux or apparmor is activated

Comment: I'm using `Debian` os and apparmor already deactivate.

Answer (score 5):

If you use CentOS 7 (as I have ). You may have SELinux turned on by default.check https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-enable-or-disable-selinux-in-centos-rhel-7/
or mount like this:

```
  volumes:
   - ./database:/var/lib/mysql:Z
   - ./_conf/mariadb.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf:Z
   - ./logs:/var/log/mysql:Z
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're running a RedHat-based distribution e.g. Fedora or CentOS, you may have SELinux turned on by default. You can automatically permit your containers to access files on the hosts by mounting with the `:Z` option, like so:

```
  volumes:
   - ./database:/var/lib/mysql:Z
   - ./_conf/mariadb.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf:Z
   - ./logs:/var/log/mysql:Z
```

Answer (score 1):

If `/var/log/mysql:/var/log/mysql` is defined as a volume then the content that reside in the container's `/var/log/mysql/` will be stored in the `/var/log/mysql/` folder on the host.

It could be possible that it is not possible to mount the `/var/lib/mysql` as SElinux or app armor is preventing this.

https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/

> Note that users on host systems with SELinux enabled may see issues
>   with this. The current workaround is to assign the relevant SELinux
>   policy type to the new data directory so that the container will be
>   allowed to access it:
>
> ```
> $ chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t /my/own/datadir
> ```

Comment: yes I agree, `./database` volume working fine and even I create file on `./logs` folder on host then it will show on container but volume not working in revers order.

Comment: If for example the mysql container from dockerhub is run and the database is stored in /var/lib/mysql, the container is rebooted then the database that reside on the host will be found in the container as well